# Is there any online serious community of Dhamma practitioners to join?

Tags: lay-buddhism, lay-practices

Not counting this site are there any communities where I can talk about the Dhamma with serious lay practitioners in facebook? Most of the groups I have been have been riddled with really toxic and judgemental people.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook: [Friday Night Study Group with Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1411848665788276/)

Meditation group:
https://meditation.sirimangalo.org/login